# Why is it necessary to type "host" before the imp command when I'm using SQL*Plus to import a dmp file into Oracle?

Tags: oracle, import, sqlplus

In SQL*Plus, I'm connected to an Oracle 11g database. When I type

```
imp help=y
```

It gives me

```
SP2-0042: unknown command "imp help=y" - rest of line ignored.
```

But when I type

```
host imp help=y
```

it gives mehelp with the import utility.

All the guides I've seen online for importing say to just type imp, without the host part. Why do I need to say host before using the utility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imp` is an operating system command, not an SQL*Plus command, so it should be run from the OS shell command line. If you insist on running it from SQL*Plus you need to use the SQL*Plus `host` command to send `imp` to the host OS for execution.